# Read two files after skipping line starting with ## from one file

Tags: perl

I want to read two files concurrently after skipping lines starting with ## from one file.

```
file1.txt:
##
##
##
header1 header2

file2.txt:
header3 header4
```

Is there any way to skip ## and afterwards read lines in both files concurrently?

```
open IN1, "file1.txt";
open IN2, "file2.txt";

if <IN1> ^## skip
while(my $one = <IN1>, my $two = <IN2>){
    print "$one\t$two";

}

Outputs:
header1 header2    header1 header2
```

Answer (score 1):

In the loop, skip file1's lines until they're valid, and `last` out when either of the files is done:

```
open my $file1, "<", "file1.txt" or die $!;
open my $file2, "<", "file2.txt" or die $!;

while (1) {
    my $file1_line = <$file1> or next;
    next if $file1_line =~ /^##/;  # skip commented lines in file1

    my $file2_line = <$file2> or next;

    last if not ($file1_line and $file2_line);

    chomp $file1_line;
    chomp $file2_line;

    print "$file1_line\t$file2_line\n";
}

close $file1;
close $file2;
```

Output:

```
$ cat file1.txt
##
##
##
header1 header2

$ cat file2.txt 
header3 header4

$ perl mysolution.pl
header1 header2 header3 header4

$
```

Comment: Use of uninitialized value $file1_line in pattern match (m//).

Comment: Ok I've updated to skip the loop if there's no content to read.

Answer (score 1):

One way: skip through each file until its marker is reached; continue reading them in a new loop

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;
die "Usage: $0 file1 file2\n" if !$file1 or !$file2;

open my $fh1, '<', $file1 or die "Can't open $file1: $!";
open my $fh2, '<', $file2 or die "Can't open $file2: $!";

# Second file's empty marker means it reads it from the beginning
my ($re_marker1, $re_marker2) = (qr/^##/, qr//);

while (<$fh1>) { last if /$re_marker1/ }; 
while (<$fh2>) { last if /$re_marker2/ };

while (1) { 
    my $l1 = <$fh1>; 
    my $l2 = <$fh2>; 
    chomp ($l1, $l2); 
 
    say "$l1  |  $l2"; 

    last if eof $fh1 or eof $fh2;
}
```

After the two `while` loops the filehandles `$fh1` and `$fh2` are positioned so to read the next line after the line with marker that was just read, each for its file.

Then you continue reading from them in another loop. That loop exits once either of the files has read its last line, checked by [eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) (returns 1 if the next read will be end-of-file). You can then test filehandles again to see which one still has something to read, if you need to print that file further. Or print from both again, `print $_ while <$fh>;`, which does nothing for the exhausted filehandle.

Note that we seldom need `eof`, this being one of rare situations where it is just the right tool.

The markers can be made into command-line options, as well. This does make a few simple assumptions around some unspecified problem details, inferred from the question.